# Get coordinates of image within a box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab the following coordinates topX, topY, bottomX, bottomY, as they represent a box around a source image.  They are equal to:

topX = X coordinate at top left corner on source image
topY = Y Coordinate at top left corner on source image
bottomX = X coordinate at bottom right corner on source image
bottomY = Y coordinate at bottom right corner on source image

Here is a sample plugin that calculates these values.  The source image width = 1024px and the height = 750px:

http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/crop_move.html

However, I have a new plugin that does more functionality than the above plugin, but I can't figure out how to get these 4 variables I need.

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/cv96e/

i tried to create my own `boxedCoords()`, based on how the original plugin calculated the values.  However i'm still new to jQuery and I can't get it to work.

anybody have an idea how I can get these 4 variables?

Comment: When do you want to get those 4 values?

Comment: I mean on drag you want those four params?

Comment: ideally it would be as the image view changes inside the window.  so it would be ondrag with the panning feature, or onclick when zooming in and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved.  For the solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/E2ahY/)